# Injecting json string into different Elasticsearch indices using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-filter

I have these sample data stored in postgresql `events` table:

```
{"playhead":0,"metadata":"{\"class\":\"Broadway\\\\Domain\\\\Metadata\",\"payload\":{\"console\":{\"command\":\"Doctrine\\\\Bundle\\\\FixturesBundle\\\\Command\\\\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand\",\"arguments\":\"'doctrine:fixtures:load' --env=prod -n\"}}}","@timestamp":"2020-05-13T18:03:24.295Z","payload":"{\"class\":\"OpenLoyalty\\\\Component\\\\Transaction\\\\Domain\\\\Event\\\\TransactionWasRegistered\",\"payload\":{\"transactionId\":\"91d83147-0280-481e-a984-c899e9720ec2\",\"transactionData\":{\"documentNumber\":\"not-matched\",\"purchasePlace\":\"wroclaw\",\"purchaseDate\":1582622706,\"documentType\":\"sell\"},\"customerData\":{\"name\":\"Jan Nowak\",\"email\":\"not_matched@example.com\",\"nip\":\"aaa\",\"phone\":\"+0954730076810\",\"loyaltyCardNumber\":\"not_matched_card_number\",\"address\":{\"street\":\"Ko\\u015bciuszki\",\"address1\":\"12\",\"city\":\"Warsaw\",\"country\":\"PL\",\"province\":\"Mazowieckie\",\"postal\":\"00-800\"}},\"items\":[{\"sku\":{\"code\":\"SKU1\"},\"name\":\"item 1\",\"quantity\":1,\"grossValue\":1,\"category\":\"aaa\",\"labels\":[{\"key\":\"test\",\"value\":\"label\"},{\"key\":\"test\",\"value\":\"label2\"}],\"maker\":\"sss\"},{\"sku\":{\"code\":\"SKU2\"},\"name\":\"item 2\",\"quantity\":2,\"grossValue\":2,\"category\":\"bbb\",\"labels\":[],\"maker\":\"ccc\"}],\"posId\":null,\"excludedDeliverySKUs\":null,\"excludedLevelSKUs\":null,\"excludedLevelCategories\":null,\"revisedDocument\":null,\"labels\":[]}}","@version":"1","id":1,"type":"OpenLoyalty.Component.Transaction.Domain.Event.TransactionWasRegistered","uuid":"91d83147-0280-481e-a984-c899e9720ec2","recorded_on":"2020-02-24T09:25:06.222986+00:00"}

 {"playhead":1,"metadata":"{\"class\":\"Broadway\\\\Domain\\\\Metadata\",\"payload\":{\"console\":{\"command\":\"Doctrine\\\\Bundle\\\\FixturesBundle\\\\Command\\\\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand\",\"arguments\":\"'doctrine:fixtures:load' --env=prod -n\"}}}","@timestamp":"2020-05-13T18:03:24.430Z","payload":"{\"class\":\"OpenLoyalty\\\\Component\\\\Customer\\\\Domain\\\\Event\\\\AssignedAccountToCustomer\",\"payload\":{\"customerId\":\"00000000-0000-474c-b092-b0dd880c07aa\",\"accountId\":\"3c067099-486a-41a8-87ca-343305126c5e\"}}","@version":"1","id":80,"type":"OpenLoyalty.Component.Customer.Domain.Event.AssignedAccountToCustomer","uuid":"00000000-0000-474c-b092-b0dd880c07aa","recorded_on":"2020-02-24T09:25:20.012550+00:00"}

{"playhead":2,"metadata":"{\"class\":\"Broadway\\\\Domain\\\\Metadata\",\"payload\":{\"console\":{\"command\":\"Doctrine\\\\Bundle\\\\FixturesBundle\\\\Command\\\\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand\",\"arguments\":\"'doctrine:fixtures:load' --env=prod -n\"}}}","@timestamp":"2020-05-13T18:03:24.430Z","payload":"{\"class\":\"OpenLoyalty\\\\Component\\\\Customer\\\\Domain\\\\Event\\\\CustomerWasMovedToLevel\",\"payload\":{\"customerId\":\"00000000-0000-474c-b092-b0dd880c07aa\",\"levelId\":\"e82c96cf-32a3-43bd-9034-4df343e50000\",\"oldLevelId\":null,\"updatedAt\":1582536320,\"manually\":false,\"removeLevelManually\":false}}","@version":"1","id":81,"type":"OpenLoyalty.Component.Customer.Domain.Event.CustomerWasMovedToLevel","uuid":"00000000-0000-474c-b092-b0dd880c07aa","recorded_on":"2020-02-24T09:25:20.014810+00:00"}
```

and many others with different `type` values.
what I'm looking for is to insert the `payload`of each these data into their appropriate index of elasticsearch. for instance data with `type` = OpenLoyalty.Component.Customer.Domain.Event.AssignedAccountToCustomer has to go into `oloy.account_details` index. and the index should be like:

```
    {
    "_index": "oloy.account_details",
    "_type": "OpenLoyalty\Component\Account\Domain\ReadModel\AccountDetails",
    "_id": "AXGjvhDQUCC0J4ATWiCP",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
    "accountId": "5a9bdb83-f7e8-442c-b06f-387e1b1e95a7",
    "customerId": "11111111-0000-474c-b092-b0dd880c07e1"
    }
  }
```

I wonder what configuration should I set for Logstash. so far I have this:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/openloyalty"
        jdbc_user => "openloyalty"
        jdbc_password => "openloyalty"
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\logstash\postgresql-42.2.12.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from events"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
            index => "???"
            document_type => "???"
            document_id => "???"
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add meta data fields to your table such as `target_index` and fill this fields in the first place when adding your DB row. then in your logstash config use data from these filed to set dynamic index name and etc. something like `index => "%{taget_index}"` could work.

Comment: @Masoud Thanks. I'll try this :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is here:

```
input {
    file{
        path => "C:/Users/Khatere Tajfar/Desktop/Log/application.log"
 start_position => "beginning"
        ignore_older => 0  
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match=>{"message"=>"%{GREEDYDATA:part1} INFO %{GREEDYDATA:part2}\{\"indexType\"\:\"%{GREEDYDATA:type}\"\,\"indexName\"\:\"%{GREEDYDATA:index}\"\,\"model\"\:\"%{GREEDYDATA:jsonpart}\"\,\"id\"\:\"%{GREEDYDATA:id}\"\}"}

    }

    mutate {
             remove_field => [ "part1","part2","message","path","host","@timestamp","@version"]
         gsub  => ["jsonpart","[\\\\\\]+","X"]
         gsub  => ["jsonpart","[\\]","X"]
         gsub  => ["jsonpart","X",""]
        }
    json {
        source => "jsonpart"
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "jsonpart"]   
    }
     mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][type]" => "%{type}" } }
         mutate { remove_field => ["type"] }

     mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][index]" => "%{index}" } }
         mutate { remove_field => ["index"] }

     mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][id]" => "%{id}" } }
         mutate { remove_field => ["id"] }

}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines} 
    elasticsearch {
            index =>  "%{[@metadata][index]}" 
            document_type =>  "%{[@metadata][type]}" 
            document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}" 
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```